# KnockOut JS Databinding clarification

Tags: knockout.js

I am a beginner to Knockout JS. I have applied the binding to `<strong>` element. I have not tried anything complex. But the binding not applied.

```
function AppViewModel()
{
    this.firstName = "Bob";
    this.lastName = "Thomas";
}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());

<p>First name: <strong data-bind:="text:firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind:="text:lastName">todo</strong></p>
```

What went wrong in binding configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're including the data-bind attribute incorrectly. Don't use :=, simply use = as you would any other HTML attribute.

Fixed code:

```
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName">todo</strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName">todo</strong></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your data binding call

Try replace your code

remove the colon after `data-bind:` and replace your code

```
<strong data-bind="text:firstName">todo</strong></p>
<strong data-bind="text:lastName">todo</strong></p>
```